# Validating if a POST value is either an email or 8-digit number in PHP

Tags: php, validation, email, post, numbers

I have been trying to implement a server-side validation of a POST value in PHP - the value should be either a valid email address or an 8-digit number.

What I've got so far is:

```
<?php

 $username = $_POST["username"];

 if (!filter_var($username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) || second-condition-about-8-digit-number-here) {

 header("Location: ../login-error/?&sessionid=$hash&securessl=true");
 die();

 }

?>
```

I'd love some guidance as to how to implement this. The input value should be either an email address OR an 8 digit number.

Comment: Hint: use `preg_match`

Comment: another hint : use `\d{8}` for 8 digit number

Comment: Why not validate on client-side before it ever POSTs back to server?

Comment: @Edward Validating it client-side is helpful, but ultimately it does need to be validated server-side.

Comment: @Edward don't trust client side validation. It can be broken simply

Comment: Would this work then: if (!filter_var($username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) or !preg_match('/\A\d{8}\z/',$username))  ?

Comment: have you searched for "anything" on this? I'm sure I'll find many results if I were to go on Google "for you", but I won't since that's "your" job. Come come now, you can do this without our help.

Comment: *"Would this work then"* - try it out and see ;-)

Comment: Tried it, didn't work - thing is, I am not familiar with regex. I'm sure I am missing something. The email validation works fine. The 8-digit number validation doesn't.

Comment: My bad - it does work. However, what seems to be the problem, is the "or" operator - it only executes the FIRST condition about the email validation, but NOT the second one.

Comment: I just used two if conditions, second one nested in the first one. Thank you everyone for the pointers!

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$username = $_POST["username"];

if (!filter_var($username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) || !preg_match('/^[0-9]{8}$/', $username)) {
    header("Location: ../login-error/?&sessionid=$hash&securessl=true");
    die();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `strlen` to get the length of a string.

As you only care about digits then you could use this approach ..

```
$length = strlen(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $username));
```

That will set `$length` to be the number of characters exist in the string `$username` that are numeric.